# replica set connectivity to mysql from python

Tags: python, mysql, high-availability

I am trying to connect from python code to mysql configured with replica set to enable high availability.
So far I tried it using SqlAlchemy but not able to have multiple instances for mysql.
Python version : 3.6
Mysql verision : 4.1.4

The connection string which I am using so far :
MYSQL_CONNECTION_STRING=mysql+mysqlconnector://%%s:%%s@localhost:3306/my_database

In normal scenario is it getting connected and working fine but through HA configuration its not getting connected.